# MySQL version 8.0.17 - Replacing only first space in string

Tags: mysql

In the table stored an a database `MySql version 8.0.17` I have this string

```
Sheriff Curtis Edward
```

I need replace in this string only the first space for this return

```
SheriffCurtis Edward
```

This will make future surname entries work even if the given surname is a double surname...

I have tried this sql but the return is wrong...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Sheriff Curtis Edward',
                 INSTR('Sheriff Curtis Edward', ' ') + 1,
                 CHAR_LENGTH('Sheriff Curtis Edward') - INSTR('Sheriff Curtis Edward', ' ')) new_string;
+---------------+
| new_string    |
+---------------+
| Curtis Edward |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Sheriff Curtis Edward', ' ', '', 1, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^(\\S+) ', '$1') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Using your `subtring()` approach, you could also extract the substring before the space and concatenate it with the substring after the space.

```
SELECT concat(substring(x.s,
                        1,
                        instr(x.s,
                              ' ')
                        - 1),
              substring(x.s,
                        instr(x.s,
                              ' ')
                        + 1,
                        char_length(x.s)
                        - instr(x.s,
                                ' ')))
       FROM (SELECT 'Sheriff Curtis Edward' s) x
```